# Is there any analog of TCPvcon which allows to close TCP connection on remote machine?

Tags: windows, console, administration, sysinternals

I started to use SysInternals suite, and it is great. But I wonder, whether there is any analog of TCPvcon, which allows to logon to remote machine, like psexec does, and then get list of TCP connections from there (similar to pslist functionality), and then to close some of connections (similar to pskill functionality).

I am speaking about windows console tools and I would like to avoid installing something on remote machine is this is possible.

Comment: Belongs on server fault.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `psexec` to run `netstat` remotely?

Comment: Do netstat close connections?